# Nested Ajax UpdatePanel in Gridview needs button control to be clicked twice

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview

I have an expandable GridView with a TemplateField that has a TextBox and a Button where, the idea is that, when the button is pressed it will save the contents of the textBox into a database. At the moment I didn't get to loading the content of the TextBox into the database as I have a problem when I'm testing it.

I have the Gridview inside an Ajax UpdatePanel and the TexBox and Button inside the TemplateField also inside an Ajax UpdatePanel.

The problem is that when the gridview is updated from a change in the triggering dropdownfield, I need to press twice in the Button to get the result I want (which at the moment is to just enter the ID in the row).

Following on another posting ([Why does a button control need to be clicked twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453/why-does-a-button-control-need-to-be-clicked-twice)), I've tried my best to contain all the information within the nested UpdatePannel. Still I can not get rid of the problem. I'm guessin that the problem is due to trying to find the TextBox control in row so that I can edit the text, but I cannot figure out how to avoid having to use FindControl.

See below code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function divexpandcollapse(divname) {var div = document.getElementById(divname);
        var img = document.getElementById('img' + divname);
        if (div.style.display == "none") {
            div.style.display = "block"; img.src = "Images/Icons/minus.jpg";
        } else { div.style.display = "none"; img.src = "Images/Icons/plus.jpg"; }
    }</script>

<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release"
    CompositeScript-ScriptMode="Release" AllowCustomErrorsRedirect="False" EnablePartialRendering="true">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_TabContainer" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DateSelection" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"> </asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:GridView ID="GV_SL" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvUserInfo_RowDataBound"
  OnRowCommand="GV_SL_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SQL_Weekly">
    <Columns>

     <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px">
     <ItemTemplate>
      <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("reporting_group") %>');">
       <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("reporting_group") %>" width="15px" border="0" src="Images/Icons/plus.jpg" /></a>
     </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="40px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Group" SortExpression="name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="reporting_group" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="reporting_group" />

    <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
       <td colspan="100%">
        <div id="div<%# Eval("reporting_group") %>" style="display: none; position: relative;
         left: 15px; overflow: auto">
          <asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
           <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Metric" HeaderText=" " HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Actual" HeaderText="Actual" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
             </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>

          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_Comments" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
           <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TB_Comments" runat="server" Text="Example: Text will be entered here"></asp:TextBox>
             <asp:Button ID="B_Save" runat="server" CommandName="AddText" CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex  %>"
              Text="Save Changes" />
             <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# eval("reporting_group")  %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
           </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
         </div>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
  </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DateSelection" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The vb Button code behind

```
Protected Sub GV_SL_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If (e.CommandName = "AddText") Then
        ' Retrieve the row index stored in the CommandArgument property.
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        ' Retrieve the row that contains the button 
        ' from the Rows collection.
        Dim row As GridViewRow = GV_SL.Rows(index)
        Dim LB_RG As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("Label1"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)
        Dim TB_Com_Control As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("TB_Comments"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)
        TB_Com_Control.Text = "Test " & "-" & LB_RG.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

I hope anyone could help me to try to identify where the problem is and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the problem by wrapping the following controls within UpdatePanel ID="UP_TabContainer" :

- GridView ID="GV_SL"
- DataSourceID="SQL_Weekly"

and excluding:

- function divexpandcollapse(divname)
- ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1"
- DropDownList ID="DateSelection"

I'm not sure why it works, but I hope it helps someone.